# Why grepping between two tags does not work with option -z? How to fix?

Tags: grep

This case:

```
$ cat t01.txt
xxxyyyzzz

$ cat t01.txt | grep -Po '(?<=xxx).*(?=zzz)'
```

results in:

```
yyy
```

which is expected.

However, this case:

```
$ cat t02.txt
xxx
yyy
zzz

$ cat t02.txt | grep -Pzo '(?<=xxx).*(?=zzz)'
```

results in:

```
<nothing>
```

which is unexpected.

Why and how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because by default, the `.` doesn't match the newline in Perl regexes. You need to either match it explicitly, or use the `s` flag to the regex:

```
$ < t02.txt grep -Pzo '(?<=xxx\n).*\n(?=zzz)'
yyy
$ < t02.txt grep -Pzo '(?s)(?<=xxx).*(?=zzz)'

yyy
```

See e.g. the [`perlre` man page](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre):

In the "Metacharacters" section:

> ```
> .   Match any single character except newline    Not in []
>     (under /s, includes newline)
> ```

and in "Modifiers":

> `s`
> Treat the string as single line. That is, change `"."` to match any character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not match.

Comment: It seems that `[\s\S]*` can also be used instead of `.*`.

Comment: @pmor, yeah, or`(.|\n)*`

Answer (score 2):

It is actually expected behavior. `.` includes any character except for line breaks. the regex you are looking for is:

```
(?<=xxx)\n*.*\n*(?=zzz)
```

here is a nice site to test your regexes, it has explanation about every part of it too, so you always know why it behaves as it does: https://regex101.com